# what is the use of development build in unity (android)

Tags: android, debugging, unity-game-engine

What is the use of the "Development Build" in Unity for Android? and what is the difference between "Development Build" and the `Debug.Log(DebugMessage)`? And also it seems like when I enabled "Development Build", my application seems to start faster. Why? what does the "Development Build" do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in development build the resources and assets are not packaged and compressed, so they would start faster.

Documentation says:

> A development build includes debug symbols and enables the Profiler.
> Note that a development build of a webplayer means that the unity3d file created
> is not LZMA compressed.

`Debug.Log(DebugMessage)` is used to print out statements to Unity console for debugging purpose.